# java.net.ProtocolException: muitos redirecionamentos do servidor

Tags: java

Preciso realizar o download de um arquivo `.zip` que se encontra no seguinte endereço: http://www1.caixa.gov.br/loterias/_arquivos/loterias/D_quina.zip

Para isso criei o seguinte método:

```
public static void downloadFile() throws IOException{
    final File file = new File("download/");
    if(!file.exists()){
        file.mkdirs();
    }
    final URL link = new URL(URL); 
    final InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(link.openStream());
    final ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int n = 0;
    while (-1!=(n=in.read(buf)))
    {
        out.write(buf, 0, n);
    }
    out.close();
    in.close();
    byte[] response = out.toByteArray();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(PATH);
    fos.write(response);
    fos.close();
}
```

Mas quando ele executa o `link.openStream()`, ocorre o seguinte erro:

```
java.net.ProtocolException: Server redirected too many  times (20)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
    at good.dowload.DownloadManager.downloadFile(DownloadManager.java:31)
    at good.dowload.DownloadManager.main(DownloadManager.java:19)
```

Como posso contornar estes redirecionamentos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é devido a não manter a sessão do usuário, mais ou menos o que o navegador faz quando você faz o download por lá, se você desabilitar os *cookies* no browser perceberá o mesmo erro =)

Como há redirecionamentos no servidor e por padrão a conexão segue estes redirecionamentos, devido ao fato de você não manter a sessão do usuário é como se toda vez fosse um novo usuário/sessão (do ponto de vista do servidor), o que acaba gerando redirecionamentos infinitos.

A sessão é normalmente feita com a ajuda de um *cookie*, então você precisa armazenar o *cookie* para que o mesmo seja usado pelos redirecionamentos, então podemos mesmo falar que iremos aceitar tudo.

Para isto, basta você adicionar o seguinte trecho antes de fazer a sua requisição HTTP:

```
CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL));
```

Em alguns casos você precisará também

Veja mais detalhes sobre o gerenciamento de *cookies* na documentação de [`CookieManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/CookieManager.html).